# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.Network

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, payu

This is little related to [Payubiz payment gateway sdk](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/releases/) integration. 
However, the main problem is related to building a project.

Whenever we try to run the application on emulator. We get the following
failure:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForAppDebug'.
>     **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.Network**

However, the application builds and run smoothly on running on a device.
We have already contacted the Payu Team for the issue. But as it is an android related problem, not the payment gateway. I feel like SO is the better place.

Emulator Details:

- Name: Nexus_4_API_19 CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
- Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 19)
- runtime.network.speed: full

SOLUTION:
Below, is a reply from PayU team. They have confirmed that they were not using any class, neither do i. But after some time/ may be some other dependency/cleaning the project. It works for the emulator as well.

[image]

Comment: What SDK level is your emulator based upon?

Comment: Please check edits. Emultor is based on SDK 19

Comment: @Shubham: have you got any solution to run the app in api level 19.
Becuase payu android demo has minimum sdkversion = 9. So it should be work in all the level from 9, Also sample apk given in root directory is working fine in api level 19, but imported project in android studio gives error same as yours.

Comment: @Jayesh please see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [android.net.Network](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html) is added in API 21. You need to use an emulator with the same or higher API level to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am testing in the different environment/emulator. Is that mean it will not work on the device as well for below 21.

Comment: Yes, it won't work on API level below 21, be it in an emulator or a real-life device.